Get a container image ID from Kubernetes (not the repo digest)
I am trying to correlate container images across a few systems that scan them in different stages of the container image lifecycle.
I saw the following method of getting the image ID using kubectl:
k get po <pod name> -o json | jq '.status.containerStatuses[] | { "image": .image, "imageID": .imageID }'

The issue with this method is that it returns the repoDigest and not the actual image ID, and in some cases I have a few different repo digests for the same image, and sometimes I only have the Image ID.
Is there another way to get the image id?

You can obtain the image ID using docker inspect, provided you have access to the K8s node where the pod is running.
Steps

Get the container ID from the pod:

kubectl get po <pod name> -o jsonpath='{.status.containerStatuses[0].containerID}'

This will return a string like docker://<container_id>.

Log in to the K8s node and use Docker CLI to get the image ID:

docker inspect <container_id> --format='{{.Image}}'

Example
I setup a local Minikube cluster with pods in the kube-system namespace:

To get the image ID of the etcd-minikube pod, first, I retreive t the container ID:

Then, I use Docker command to get the image ID:

Which matches with my docker images output:


NOTE: To connect the Docker CLI to the Minikube cluster (instead of your host machine), run eval $(minikube docker-env) first.


Thanks! I though of that, but I don't have access to the nodes...
